# Responsiveness of a Grid inside the scrollable div with frozen columns in syncfusion

Tags: css, syncfusion

I have a grid inside the scrollable div, 4 buttons just below the Grid in a page(razor view). I have written some media query to set the height of a div in different resolution. Based on that the number of rows displaying on the page also changes. Now the headers need to be frozen when the user scrolls the grid. i am not setting the height of a grid basically I dont want to set since css media queries will take care of it because I have a grid inside the div now.

To have frozen rows, need to set AllowScrolling(true), Height of a grid & FrozenColumns(2).FrozenRows(0) but with this responsive of a grid doesnt work properly since  frozen rows/cols doesnt work with responsiveness of grid.
do we have any alternative for this? I am hoping that since I have a grid inside the div(height set in css for any resolution) can we set the height of a grid based on the screen resolution ?

```
<div class="row scrollDiv" style="overflow-y: auto;"> 
@(Html.EJ().Grid<DatabaseColumnInfo>("TableColumnGrid")
          .Datasource(Model)
          .AllowSorting()
          .IsResponsive(true)
          .AllowResizing(true)
          //.AllowScrolling(true)            
          //.ScrollSettings(col =>
          //{
          //    col.Height(300);
          //    col.FrozenColumns(2).FrozenRows(0);
          //})
          .ClientSideEvents(evt => evt.RowSelected("onRowSelected"))
          .Columns(col =>
          {
              col.Field("Name").HeaderText("Column name").Width(300).Add();
              col.Field("DataType").HeaderText("Type").Add();
          }))
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1366px) { .scrollDiv { height: 368px; } }
@media (min-width: 1367px) and (max-width: 1920px) { .scrollDiv { height: 720px; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the grid height to adapt to the required  resolution set the width and height in the scrollSettings property of grid to 100%. Refer the below sample and code example for details.

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/202776/ze/Grid-1825010219.zip

```
enter code here
<div> 
    @(Html.EJ().Grid<object>("FlatGrid") 
              .Datasource((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.datasource) 

                 ….. 

              .IsResponsive() 
              .AllowResizing() 
              .AllowScrolling() 
              .ScrollSettings(col => 
              { 
                  col.Height("100%"); col.Width("100%"); 
                  col.FrozenColumns(2).FrozenRows(0); 
              }) 
              .EditSettings(edit => { edit.AllowAdding().AllowDeleting().AllowEditing().EditMode(EditMode.Normal); }) 

               …..
```

Please refer the below documentation.

https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejgrid#members:scrollsettings